# Flot charts show two lines in the chart

Tags: javascript, html, plot

I am using http://www.flotcharts.org/ charts. I want to show more lines. This examle (
http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/realtime/index.html) shows one line updating with ajax. As of their documentation I added two series, but it didn't work. 
          `

```
        function update() {

         plot.setData({ data: getRandomData()},
                { data:  getRandomData2()});
         plot.draw();
          setTimeout(update, 5000);
    }
```

My source is same as above example and I additionally wrote getRandomdata2() method same as  gtRandomData().

```
function getRandomData2() {
        if (data.length > 0)
            data2 = data.slice(1);

        while (data2.length < totalPoints) {
            var prev = data2.length > 0 ? data2[data2.length - 1] : 50,
                z =Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);;
            if (z < 0) {
                y = 0;
            } else if (z > 50) {
                z = 100;
            }

            data2.push(z);
        }
        var res = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data2.length; ++i) {
            res.push([i, data2[i]]);

            console.log('data : '+data2[i]);
        }

        return res;
    }
```

Here is how I create the plot

```
    var plot = $.plot("#placeholder", [
                                        { data: getRandomData()},
                                        { data:  getRandomData2()}
                                    ], {

        series: {
            shadowSize: 0   // Drawing is faster without shadows
        },
        yaxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100
        },
        xaxis: {
            show: false
        }
    });
```

Please let me know where the problem exists ? I want to know show 2 lines something like [this](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/interacting/index.html)

Comment: How did you call getRandomData2? Did you pass the data to `plot.setData`?

Comment: @AnthonyKong. I updated my question. Please check update() method ( I think the setData() method should be changed.. )method callings. I modified the code and retried, still not working..

Comment: Once I called the set data method function update() {
    plot.setData([ {data:getRandomData()}, { data:getRandomData2()} ]);
         plot.draw();
   setTimeout(update, 5000);
  }`  it worked..

Comment: @Anthony Kong. Yes. Thanks for your guidance with 'plot.setData'

Comment: I made the very same ajusts in my example, but, looks like the two series are "match" in the ghaphics. Does anybody knows what could be wrong?